# Move object in a circle in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to move my player in a circle, based on a center transform `centerOfGravity` which is defined when the player enters a trigger2d.

I check for the distance to the center every frame once the player is grounded

```
public float CheckDistanceToCenterOfGravity() => distToCenterOfGravity = Vector2.Distance(centerOfGravity, transform.position);
```

I set the movement speed I want for the player based on a normalized input (workspace being a stored Vector2).

```
public void SetVelocityX(float velocity) {
    workspace.Set(velocity, CurrentVelocity.y);
    RB2D.velocity = workspace;
    CurrentVelocity = workspace;
}
```

Using this I'm trying to move the player in a circle using the following function which is called every frame

```
private void MovePlayerInACircle() {
    player.SetVelocityX(playerDataSO.movementVelocity * xInput);
    currentVelocityX = player.CurrentVelocity.x;

    player.playerRotation += (currentVelocityX * Time.deltaTime);
    float x = Mathf.Cos(player.playerRotation) * player.distToCenterOfGravity;
    float y = Mathf.Sin(player.playerRotation) * player.distToCenterOfGravity;
    player.transform.position = player.centerOfGravity + new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

However, the player seems to be getting stuck on the same X axis as the center, and will only move along the X axis

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might be able to avoid the calculations all together by using `player.transform.RotateAround(player.centerOfGravity, new Vector3(0,0,1), currentVelocityX * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: @avariant just put is as the answer, not a comment. this is the best way to do what he wants

Answer (score 0):

Unity does expose a way to rotate a transform around a specific point (instead of around the local zero point of the transform).

[Transform.RotateAround](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) allows you to specify a point (and an axis) to rotate around.  This would allow you to remove all the calculations you are doing to calculate your "circle" and would do all of that for you.

```
player.transform.RotateAround(player.centerOfGravity, new Vector3(0,0,1), currentVelocityX * Time.deltaTime);
```

One thing to note, this call will move the position of your transform, but it will also rotate it.  If that is undesirable (ie. you want your object to always be pointing in a fixed direction), you may need to reset your rotation after each call.

```
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

or something like that.